# Airflow- dag_id could not be found issue when using kubernetes executor

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetesexecutor

I am using airflow stable helm chart and using Kubernetes Executor, new pod is being scheduled for dag but its failing with dag_id could not be found issue. I am using git-sync to get dags. Below is the error and kubernetes config values. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Error:

```
[2020-07-01 23:18:36,939] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2020-07-01 23:18:36,940] {dagbag.py:396} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/dags/etl/sampledag_dag.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 523, in run
    dag = get_dag(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 149, in get_dag
    'parse.'.format(args.dag_id))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: sampledag  . Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
```

Config:

```
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DELETE_WORKER_PODS: false
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_REPO: git@git.com/dags.git
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_BRANCH: master
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_DAGS_FOLDER_MOUNT_POINT: /dags
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_SSH_KEY_SECRET_NAME: git-secret
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_REPOSITORY: airflow-repo
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG: tag
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__RUN_AS_USER: "50000"
```

sampledag

```
import logging
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator
import os

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
}

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


try:
    print("Entered try block")
    with models.DAG(
            dag_id='sampledag',
            schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
            start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:
     
        print("Initialized dag")
               kubernetes_min_pod = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
                # The ID specified for the task.
                task_id='trigger-task',
                # Name of task you want to run, used to generate Pod ID.
                name='trigger-name',
                namespace='scheduler',
                in_cluster = True,
     
                cmds=["./docker-run.sh"],
                is_delete_operator_pod=False,
                image='imagerepo:latest',
                image_pull_policy='Always',
                dag=dag)

        print("done")

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    logging.error("Error at {}, error={}".format(__file__, str(e)))
    raise
```

Comment: Did you create the `sampledag_dag.py` file? And if so can you share the contents please?

Comment: @joebeeson updated question with sampledag file, the same dag is working with Celery Executor but its failing only for Kubernetes Exector

Comment: please do visit this link, issue have been solved https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13680

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding the following to my config:

```
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_SUBPATH: repo/
```

What was happening is that the init container will download your dags in `[AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_DAGS_FOLDER_MOUNT_POINT]/[AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_SYNC_DEST]` and `AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_SYNC_DEST` by default is `repo`  (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#git-sync-dest)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the problem could be incurred from the difference in your setup that causes: `/opt/airflow/dags/dags/etl/sampledag_dag.py` and `AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_DAGS_FOLDER_MOUNT_POINT: /dags`

I'd double check that these are what you want, and are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while trying to use Kubernetes Executor using stable helm airflow chart. In my case, I was able to resolve it by changing
`AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__RUN_AS_USER: "50000"` to `AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_SYNC_RUN_AS_USER: "65533"` in the `env` section of helm chart.

Same value is mentioned in this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#git-sync-run-as-user)

I came to this conclusion as the init container (git sync) which was running before the temporary worker pod came up was not able to clone/sync the git dags to the worker pods. In my case, there was a permissions error (even when kube secret for ssh clone was correctly passed)

Note:

- the git-sync [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) returns no error even if it fails to fetch the DAGs
- Kubernetes [debugging information for init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/)

```sh
kubectl get pods -n [NAMESPACE]
kubectl logs -n [NAMESPACE] [POD_ID] -c git-sync
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same issue, I solved it with the suggestion from @gtrip to set the UID of the git-sync run user to 65533.

I would add the following debug hints:

- the git-sync [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) returns no error even if it fails to fetch the DAGs
- Kubernetes [debugging information for init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/)

```sh
kubectl get pods -n [NAMESPACE]
kubectl logs -n [NAMESPACE] [POD_ID] -c git-sync
```